# What is your alternative for not using session in REST API in this case

Tags: php, laravel, api, rest, laravel-5.8

I'm using this method for my API controller:

```
public function register(Request $request)
    {
        // Validation Data
        $validData = $this->validate($request, [
            'user_input' => 'required|regex:/^09\d{9}$/|max:11|min:11',
            'user_full_name' => 'nullable|max:20|min:3',
        ]);
        
        Session::put('user_full_name', $request->user_full_name);
        
        $sms = new SendSms(request()->all()['user_input'],43,request()->all());
        $sms->send();
        
        return response([
            'data' => 'verification code is sent',
            'status' => 200
        ]);
    }
```

As you can see I have set a session in the method that contains user name:

```
Session::put('user_full_name', $request->user_full_name);
```

But this is wrong because I'm not using the benefits of REST API and REST shouldn't come with sessions.

And also I DO need to know the entered user name and get that data for the next steps and that is why I used sessions.

So the question is what is the alternative way of doing this that is suitable & standard in REST API?

Comment: So don't put it in session, why you need it anyway?

Comment: @Justinas Then how can I understand the entered user name that a client has written and register him with the given data !!!

Comment: Write special service where you persist current user info. Then to `$this->auth->getFullName()`, because each request must be authorized before access, because of stateless nature of REST Api

Comment: But for what purpose are you putting the name in the first place !!

Comment: Since this is an API, you can always get the full name from ``api token`` or ``JWT token`` or whatever authentication method you're using!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of server side sessions we send the session data along with every request. This makes the communication stateless and scalable. As of the techniques, the simplest is sending username and password with every request in an [Authorization header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization). Somewhat more complicated that after the first successful authentication with the username and password, the server sets a different value with for example the user id and signs it with its private key. In the next request the client can send back the user id along with the signature and the server can check with the public key whether it is signed by the private key. You can even separate the signature giving service from the signature checking service. So for example you can do something like `auth.example.com` and `api.example.com` and the `api.example.com` accepts only the signed stuff, but not the username and password. An additional layer is encrypting both the user id and the signature, so it will be harder to copy them and adding an expiration time, so it will be harder to replay the request. Signing each request is the safest, but the most expensive way of doing this. And ofc. you need SSL.

In your upper case there is no user id, because it is registration. In that case just store the entire half filled form in the client. If it doesn't have javascript or some server side language, then maybe inside a cookie and send it back to the server along with the verification code.

Another way of doing this is creating a temporary transaction type of resource on the server with a very long random id and the client can know the id of the resource and it sends back the transaction id along with the verification code. This solution requires server resources, so it is somewhat similar to session management, but it is a good compromise if you struggle keeping the session entirely on the client and when you need eventual consistency, multi tab forms, multi step processes, etc. In the upper case I would rather use the first method unless the verification code goes on a completely different communication channel like SMS, android app, etc. and there is no way or you don't want them to type it to the client manually e.g. to verify they need to click on a link arrived in SMS to their smartphone.

Comment: _"separate`auth.example.com` and `api.example.com`, which accepts only the signed stuff, but not the username and password"_ - such a good piece of advice, that I wish more people followed

Answer (score 2):

if you are asking for an alternativ you can go with Laravel Passport or sanctum that using JSON Web token (JWT). JWT is common standar for API protection, i'am not going to write some tutorial on how to do that because there are plenty of them.

Answer (score 1):

First Off, I wouldn't recommend using Nullable Data for Verification of any sort. This comes from your validation context, I believe you should make `'user_full_name' => 'required'`  since you'll be using it for verification.

Secondly, I don't think Session or any alternative is a good way of solving this scenario, I'll rather protect the verification route with the auth middleware, [Issue and return a Sanctum API Token](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#issuing-api-tokens)

```
$token = $request->user()->createToken($request->user_full_name);
return response([
        'data' => 'verification code is sent',
        'token' => $token
        'status' => 200
    ]);
```

I'll then retrieve the user using the token that'll come as Authorization Header when the user enters the code, then check the code against the sent code for verification. (I'll persist the verification code too).

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to share a few thoughts on the subject.

Using Sessions, or passing authentication fields in every request is still  using sessions, from a strictly "stateless" perspective.

If you are dealing with a process, a series of states where one leads/feeds the next, it's not really a "stateless" process.

However, if you are simply serving resources, then yes perhaps a truly stateless approach is possible.

---

But no matter how you slice it, a process will require state. The only question is, where it is held, verified and the details on how it gets transported to and from your services.

Cookies, JWT or even URL encoded state are all not stateless, it's just a matter of how you choose to model how that state is transmitted, ingested verified and maintained.

---

So all that to say, your current solution, is not "wrong", it's just one possible implementation of managing the state of your application between requests.

If your application is running within a browser and not a command line, you automatically get Cookies, Headers and Sessions with every request, so you should feel free to use them.

If however you are using AJAX requests, where you must manually supply/define your headers and maintain Sessions, then yes you may want to model your state using JWT or other methods.

---

As for how do you maintain an awareness of your users data between request without revalidating their fields, that is exactly what tokens are for.

You then would pass those tokens between requests, then retrieve the fields by referencing the token with any associated records.

You then would manage the life/rate limits of that token in your application server/services.

---

Anyways, perhaps that is useful, insight.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you need that value for a function that will be baked later from the API (another request), but information is incomplete. If you need that, there are a couple alternatives. One is returning that value to the client, so it can be used on a subsequent API call. Another is storing data in the database with some id or token, and return that id or token in the response so the client can use it in subsequent API calls and you can use that value to retrieve the data from the database.

The second method is better when there is a lot of data that the next API call needs. The first mentor is better for a few data points.